# Query Most Recent Previous value in Webi

Tags: webi

I have the following data - we'll call them visits for simplicity's sake. I need to make decisions on how to handle each client in their current visit based on exit destination data from their most recent previous completed visit. It seems that I should be able to find the most recent exit at the query and not have to use Rank and pull a whole lot of unnecessary data into the report. The report is large and covers thousands of clients with hundreds of entries/visits. I can use rank and find the exit destination for each client where rank=2, but I'd like to complete the evaluation at the query level, because my gut hunch is that it will be more efficient if it's not slogging through irrelevant data.

```html
<style type="text/css">
.tg  {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}
.tg td{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:black;}
.tg th{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:black;}
.tg .tg-0lax{text-align:left;vertical-align:top}
</style>
<table class="tg">
  <tr>
    <th class="tg-0lax">Client</th>
    <th class="tg-0lax">Entry Date</th>
    <th class="tg-0lax">Exit Date</th>
    <th class="tg-0lax">Exit Destination</th>
    <th class="tg-0lax">Note</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">10/1/2019</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax"></td>
    <td class="tg-0lax"></td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">Current</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">6/9/2019</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">8/10/2019</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">Rehab Facility</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">Need the value from this exit destination</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">5/1/2019<br></td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">5/8/2019</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">Home</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">Ignore</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">2</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">9/15/2019</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax"></td>
    <td class="tg-0lax"></td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">Current</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">2</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">8/1/2019<br></td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">8/15/2019</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">Home</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">Need the value from this exit destination</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">3</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">9/16/2019</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax"></td>
    <td class="tg-0lax"></td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">Current</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">3</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">8/9/2019</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">8/10/2019</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">No Exit Interview</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">Need the value from this exit destination</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? You'll get more helpful answers if you can share what you've tried and how it's given you unsatisfactory results.

Comment: So far, I have basic queries which identify positive or negative outcomes based on exit destination. I forgot to take into account that some clients will have dozens of exits and I'm getting a lot of false hits on positive outcomes where clients with negative outcomes may have had a previous positive outcome. I use a minus query to remove anyone who had a positive outcome from those who have negative outcomes. I suspect I need to have one query (instead of 2) on exits and sort based on outcome internally using rank and a where clause to return the most recent exit destination.